# Movie or TV show with super heroes, dinosaurs and portals

Tags: story-identification, super-hero, dinosaurs

I have seen a preview to a movie or TV series on Netflix. The preview showed some super heroes (I believe) and they were walking around a city with large buildings. There were dinosaurs in the background and I believe they were just coming from or going to a portal. I have tried looking, but I just can't find out what it was. It is a newer show, not something old.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Animated or live action?

Comment: Terra Nova mostly fits, there's no superheroes but there are cities, dinosaurs, and portals. It's from 2011 and used to be on netflix

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This sounds like a preview for the [Season 3 premiere episode](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6403446/) of *DC’s Legends of Tomorrow*. The episode is called "Aruba-con", and deals with the fall out from some timey-wimey mess made by the heroes, including dinosaurs wandering around modern-day USA and them subsequently being herded back through some portals:

[image: A T-rex is entering into a rectangular portal in the middle of a large street; behind it 3 heroes run away with a portal about to open to their left. Destruction and more portals are seen in the distance of the city]

According to @FuzzyBoots, this episode is indeed available on Netflix and is featured in the series preview on said platform.

Comment: You can see the last minute of Season 2 and the dinosaures here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7cV0dFUGVqc . No spoiler (except which characters survive the two first seasons).